# Avoiding Callback Hell with Multiple Meteor Method calls on Client

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, meteor, promise

I have multiple Meteor.calls, where each methods depends on the response of another Meteor method.

Client

```
Meteor.call('methodOne', function(err, resOne){
    if(!err){
        Meteor.call('methodTwo', resOne, function(err, resTwo){
            if(!err){
                Meteor.call('methodThree', resTwo, function(err, resThree){
                    if(err){
                        console.log(err);
                    }
                })
            }
        });
    }
});
```

From Meteor's documentation I know

"Methods called on the client run asynchronously, so you need to pass a callback in order to observe the result of the call."

I know I can create yet another Meteor Method on the server to execute methods 'methodOne', 'MethodTwo', 'MethodThree' wrapped using Meteor.async, or sequentially without the callback all together. But I am worried this path will cause my meteor methods to get bloated and entangled, leading to spaghetti code. I would rather keep each Meteor method simple with one job to do and find a more elegant way of chaining the calls on the client. Any ideas, is there any way to use Promises on the client?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Since the other answer suggests RSVP this answer will suggest [Bluebird](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird) which is actually the fastest promise library when running [real benchmarks](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/master/benchmark/README.md). Rather than [a](http://mrale.ph/blog/2014/02/23/the-black-cat-of-microbenchmarks.html) [micro](http://mrale.ph/blog/2013/08/14/hidden-classes-vs-jsperf.html) [benchmark](http://ericlippert.com/2013/05/14/benchmarking-mistakes-part-one/) that does not really measure anything meaningful. Anyway, I'm not picking it for performance, I'm picking it here because it's also the easiest to use and the one with the best debuggability.

Unlike the other answer, this one also does not suppress errors and the cost of making the function return a promise is marginal since no promise constructor is called.

```
var call = Promise.promisify(Meteor.call, Meteor);

var calls = call("methodOne").
            then(call.bind(Meteor, "methodTwo")).
            then(call.bind(Meteor, "methodThree"));

calls.then(function(resThree){
    console.log("Got Response!", resThree);
}).catch(function(err){
    console.log("Got Error", err); 
});
```

Comment: I honestly can say that I learned something - I never really got into promisifying and/or chaining promises, but if anything more than very simple cases go into play, bluebird indeed seems like the best choice, not only performance wise. Thanks!

Comment: @benjamin will this work using fibers inside the server side method call? I am doing external http.get calls and having fibers return a promise.

Comment: @JasonCochran sure, it would work - although a "more meteor" way would be `Meteor.wrapAsync` and use the code as if it is synchronous. The "promises response" to that is using generators and coroutines (Bluebird.coroutine). Personally I prefer the promises version but both are viable (as are plain callbacks). Just to be extra clear - it would work.

Comment: I am accepting this as the answer with one caveat, just like you point out Meteor.wrapAsync is the "meteor way" of managing multiple asynchronous functions on the server, I was hoping for a meteor package or meteor specific way of managing promises on the client rather than a generic library.

Answer (score 3):

EDIT: You're probably better off looking at @Benjamin Gruenbaum answer, which not only results in better performance, but also provides much more concise code.

Promises - yes there is.

I like [RSVP](https://github.com/tildeio/rsvp.js/) very much, why? Simply because it's the fastest one. (quick benchmark: [jsperf](http://jsperf.com/bluebird-vs-rsvp/54) ).

Here's quick re-write of your code:

```
var promise = new RSVP.Promise(function(fulfill, reject) {
  Meteor.call('methodOne', '', function(err, resOne) {
    if (!err) {
      return reject(err);
    }
    fulfill(resOne);
  });
});

promise.then(function(resOne) {
  return new RSVP.Promise(function(fulfill, reject) {
    Meteor.call('methodTwo', resOne, function(err, resTwo) {
      if (err) {
        return reject(err);
      }
      fulfill(resTwo);
    });
  });
}).then(function(resTwo) {
  return new RSVP.Promise(function(fulfill, reject) {
    Meteor.call('methodTwo', resTwo, function(err, resThree) {
      if (err) {
        reject(err);
      }
      fulfill(resThree);
    });
  });
}).then(function(resThree) {
  // resThree is available - continue as you like
  console.log(resThree);
}).catch(function(err) {
  console.log(err);
});
```

That's the way to prevent "the ever rightward drift" of your code.

Promises are cool, use them.

Comment: RSVP is by no measure the fastest one. That benchmark is broken since it does not invoke the JIT. The JSPerf is indicative of nothing. Moreover - bluebird will be much much much faster than RSVP in this example since you are promisifying the function manually which allocates another closure. You're also ignoring errors but that's another story.

Comment: The benchmark measures the latency of the used scheduler (which you can set with `setScheduler` when using bluebird), not the performance of promises.

Comment: Also in case you didn't notice, your code is much more complicated and verbose than the original callback code.. if he simply wanted to remove "rightward drift" of the code that would have been trivial by naming the callbacks.

Comment: Those are very valid comments - @Benjamin Gruenbaum answer is especially enlightening here. Bar incredibly simple cases, bluebird is indeed much better choice. Updating answer to reflect that (and catch potential errors as well).

Answer (score 3):

Your approach on the client results in a lot more round trips between the server and the browser. I know you indicated that you were worried about spaghetti code on the server and I don't have visibility into your application as you do, but just going by the example you provide, it seems like an ideal place to wrap all three calls on the server and make only one call from the client, IMHO.

Comment: +1, I don't think this is the answer to this question but after doing some more work and research I agree this is the best practice in conjunction with a robust design pattern to manage all of your apps meteor methods.

Comment: Thanks. However, I do think it answers your question. It does "avoid callback hell" and is the best design for the example code that you showed.