# Wait for completing Meteor.call before collection insert

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, meteor, async-await

I'm making a MeteorJS app, where I fetch multiple files from remote API.

One API record can have multiple files - I want to download them, save in my `Media` collection and retrieve their id to store into another collection (e.g. `NotMedia`):

```
// Client side: apiArr is an array with api json objects
for(var a in apiArr){
  var pic1_id = Meteor.call('saveMedia', apiArr[a].image1_url);
  var pic2_id = Meteor.call('saveMedia', apiArr[a].image2_url);
  var collection = {
    name: apiArr[a].name,
    description: apiArr[a].desc,
    image1_id: pic1_id,
    image2_id: pic2_id
  };
  NotMedia.insert(collection);
}
```

my Meteor method:

```
//Server side:
Meteor.methods({
  saveMedia: function(media){
    var file = new FS.File();
    file.attachData(media, function(err){
      if(err){
        throw err;
      }
      file.origin_name = media;
      var id = Media.insert(file);
      return id;
    });
  },
});
```

But when I retrieve saved `NotMedia` record, `image_id`'s are `undefined`. I understand that `NotMedia` insertion is finished faster than saving image files, but how can I synchronize that/wait for `Meteor.calls` to finish?

Comment: You can do this using promises:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28633187/avoiding-callback-hell-with-multiple-meteor-method-calls-on-client

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this: [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21542356/2525291) && [Meteor.wrapAsync](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_wrapasync)

wrapAsync is what you are looking for.

Here is a quick code snippet. Hope this helps.

```js
Meteor.methods({
  saveMedia: function(media) {
    var asyncFunc = function(arg1, arg2, callback) {
      var file = new FS.File();
      file.attachData(media, function(err) {
        if (err) {
          callback(err, null);
        }
        file.origin_name = media;
        var id = Media.insert(file);
        callback(null, id);
      });      
    };
    return Meteor.wrapAsync(asyncFunc);
  }
});
```

Comment: Your answer might be right, but you could improve it by giving example code.

Comment: I've tried `Meteor.wrapAsync` in various ways, but without success - code example would be great

Answer (score -2):

Two things wrong here:

1) if you're using `Meteor.call` on a method that's defined on the server, `Meteor.call` will return `undefined` because it's calling the method asynchronously. For `Meteor.call` on server-side methods, you *have* to supply a callback function instead.

2) it looks like you're calling an asynchronous function on the server side, and you can't do that.

```
Meteor.methods({
  saveMedia(media) {
    let file = new FS.File();

    // this takes a callback func.. that tells me this is asynchronous - bad!
    file.attachData(media, function (err) {
      if (err) {
        throw err;
      }
      file.origin_name = media;
      return Media.insert(file);
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: I've tried this 'callback hell' but it doesn't work well so I've decided to ask this question..

Comment: Edited my answer.. I see the problem. Don't use asynchronous operations in methods.