# Meteor pattern for multiple method calls sequential callbacks

Tags: javascript, meteor, methods

I keep running into this pattern when coding in Meteor where I find myself making multiple method calls nested within each other - first method fires, then in the callback, a second one fires which is dependent on the first one's result, etc.  Is there a better pattern for using multiple methods without nested method calls inside callbacks?  The code quickly gets messy.

```
Meteor.call('unsetProduct', product._id, omitObj, function(err, result) {
if(!err) {

    Meteor.call('editProduct', product._id, object, function(err, result) {
        if(!err) {

            //if no error, then continue to update the product template
                Meteor.call('editProductTemplate', self._id, obj, function(err, result) {
                    if(!err) {
                        //call some other method

                    }
                    else {
                        FormMessages.throw(err.reason, 'danger');
                    }
                }); 
        }
        else {
            FormMessages.throw(err.reason, 'danger');
        }
    });//end edit product

}
else {
    AppMessages.throw(err.reason, 'danger');
}
```

});`

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to put all of this on a single server method? That's really the easiest way to handle these things when possible.

Comment: It seems to be better to use a single method that emits the relevant errors. If you want a better design pattern for async processes, you can use a future/promise.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [reactive-method](https://atmospherejs.com/simple/reactive-method) package. I think it does exactly what you need: it wraps asynchronous `Meteor.call`s into synchronous code. With it, your code would look cleaner, like

```
try {
    const result = ReactiveMethod.call('unsetProduct', product._id, omitObj);
} catch (error) {
    AppMessages.throw(err.reason, 'danger');
}

try {
    const nestedResult = ReactiveMethod.call('editProduct', product._id, object);
} catch (error) {
    FormMessages.throw(err.reason, 'danger');
}

try {
    const evenMoreNestedResult = ReactiveMethod.call('editProductTemplate', self._id, obj);
} catch (error) {
    FormMessages.throw(err.reason, 'danger');
}
```

Which will look nicer when you add some logic inside `try` statements.

Comment: I just saw this question that is the same as mine, but has a few other suggestions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28633187/avoiding-callback-hell-with-multiple-meteor-method-calls-on-client?rq=1

Comment: Surely that answer is great. But I personally don't like promises (for their ugly dot syntax) and stick to making code synchronous, or at least looking like it's synchronous. In ES6, there's async/await that makes code look synchronous while executing it in async manner. I believe ReactiveMethod developers will adopt it soon, since, under the hood, it's based on Promises, too.